# How to display sheet view in NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

How do I implement the view in following image.
The view which appears when <kbd>+</kbd> button is clicked in `System Preferences > Network`
[image]

---

I have following questions:

1. Does this view system has a specific name (like popover), because I have seen it in many places in Mac.
2. How to implement it in IB ?
3. Can this be done in a popover window instead of NSWindow ?(or is it only possible in NSWindow like toolbar)

Update:
Updating the title for better visibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cocoa these are called sheets. Take a look at the [sheet programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html), however, this is terribly out of date!

You need to call `-beginSheet:completionHandler:` on the window you want to display the sheet. If you have single-window application you can ask the AppDelegate for the window and launch the sheet like so,

```
// This code should be in AppDelegate which implement the -window method
NSWindow *targetWindow = [self window]; // the window to which you want to attach the sheet
NSWindow *sheetWindow = self.sheetWindowController.window // the window you want to display at a sheet

// Now start-up the sheet
[targetWindow beginSheet:sheetWindow completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {

        switch (returnCode) {

            case NSModalResponseCancel:
                NSLog(@"%@", @"NSModalResponseCancel");
                break;

            case NSModalResponseOK:
                NSLog(@"%@", @"NSModalResponseOK");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
```

You will notice that when the sheet completes it will return a certain modal response --- we will return to this point in a shortly.

Next you need to implement the content that you want to display in the sheet; this must be done in an NSWindow. I find it much easier to use a NSWindowController and implement the window in a separate XIB file. For example, see below,

[image: NSWindow containing a items to be displayed in the sheet.]

Now you need to implement the code *in your custom NSWindowController* (or plain NSWindow if you are old-school and love to manage your own NIB loading) which will issue the correct modal response. Here I have hooked up the cancel and OK buttons to the following actions methods,

```
- (IBAction)cancelButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [[[self window] sheetParent] endSheet:self.window returnCode:NSModalResponseCancel];
}

- (IBAction)OKButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [[[self window] sheetParent] endSheet:self.window returnCode:NSModalResponseOK];
}
```

The model response will get sent to your completion handler block.

[Sample project on github.](https://github.com/danieljfarrell/CocoaSheets)

Comment: thanks. What about displaying the sheet in popover ?

Comment: Popovers are a different technology. You wouldn't display a sheet in a popover, you just need to give the popover a view to display. Read the human interface guidelines for when and where to use popover vs. sheets. Popovers are pretty new technology in Cocoa and the API is much nicer.

Comment: Wow you are right and Apple's doc are really out of date, there is brand new and shiny answer above. Also example project on github because I had to figure it out myself.